# docker started via shelljs not responding to input in interactive mode

Tags: node.js, shell, docker

I am starting my docker containers via [shelljs](https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs).

The container has a sh script that is running on startup.

This is behaving as intended when the output of the container is only passive.

But when start the container without startscript and try to give some manual input (like cd dir), the docker interactive shell is not responding to my input.

So my question: is it possible to use shelljs to start a docker container in interactive mode and interact with this container as if i had started it directly from the command line?

here is a example shelljs command i like to run:

```
exec("docker run -it --name=test user:image", { silent: false });
```

Comment: Try this if it helps [http://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line][1]

Cheers..


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line